# Where to put OnItemClickListener for dynamic ListView?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, onclicklistener

A little background info for my Android program:

- My main activity is using a PagerAdapter to show 5 different fragments.
- Using a custom adapter class which extends ArrayAdapter for a custom object class
- One of the fragments has a ListView, which uses the custom adapter to populate the ListView

My question is, where should I be putting the OnClickItemListener? I want each ListView row, when clicked, to open to it's specific individual page showing further details about it (so I will be making another activity which will be populated with the same custom object class information).

Should I be putting the OnClickItemListener in the fragment class or the customer adapter page?

And please correct me if I am wrong in wanting to use the OnClickItemListener.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably be best if you keep it in the fragment with the list. The fragment should contain the adapter and the listview

Comment: Staying on the same topic, do you happen to know what the code would be to go to that specific page? Ie. click on row 1 > goes to specific row 1 info page. click on row 2 > goes to row 2 page. etc etc

Comment: You probably want to write a public method in your Activity for that, since your Activity should contain the PagerAdapter. In the listfragment you can then do this: YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity; activity.someMethodToChangeView(somepagenumber);